# Case statement based on partition of data

Tags: case, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm trying to categorize my data based on the existence of text within a variable for each id that I have. For example:

```
ID Groupname
1   A
1   B
1   F
2   D
2   B
2   C
```

The result I want would be

```
ID Groupname  Category
1   A           AF
1   B           AF
1   F           AF
2   D           D
2   B           D
2   C           D
```

I want to do something like the following but I cannot get it to work

```
Select * ,
CASE WHEN A,F in groupname (partition by id) THEN AF
     WHEN D in groupname (partition by id) THEN D
      ....
     ELSE null END
FROM table
```

Answers in postgres/redshift would greatly be appreciated!

EDIT:

I fixed the problem with F that JNevill brought up.

EDIT2:

One user suggested a simple solution that works if you only need 1 combination. E.g. If i see F or A then it's AF. But if I need to see A and F it will not work.

Here is the simple solution:

WHEN sum(CASE WHEN combo in (20,28,19,27) then 1 end) over (partition by log_id)=1 then 1000

If i want combinations I have to do the following which creates very long code. Is there an easier way to do this?

WHEN sum(CASE WHEN combo in (20,28,19,27) then 1 end) over (partition by log_id)=1
    and sum(CASE WHEN groupid in (1048,598,428) then 1 end) over (partition by log_id)=1
    then 1000

Comment: You don't have `F` as a `GROUPNAME` in your sample data. Why would `B` pick up the value `AF`? What if `ID` `2` had an A and a F as well. Would it get a `D` or an `AF` or would there be new records for `2` to handle a situation like that?

Answer (score 0):

you're right about case with partitioning, it just requires conditional aggregate

```
select
 *
,case
    when sum(case when groupname in ('A','F') then 1 end) over (partition by id)=1 then 'AF'
    when sum(case when groupname in ('D') then 1 end) over (partition by id)=1 then 'D'
end as category
from t
```

one note is that if you want only the pair of A and F to make AF category it's not possible with this syntax... `count(distinct case...) over ()` returns an error and requires more complex query, but from what I see you don't need it since F is not in your sample data

Comment: Hey there thanks for this, I fixed the problem with F that you and JNevill brought up.

How would you do combinations then? I have the following code but it is so long and messy and we have to build out a massive query to categorize a lot of data and I would prefer to use cleaner code. Here's what I'm working with.

I just apply an and statement to what you did. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

WHEN sum(CASE WHEN combo in (20,28,19,27) then 1 end) over (partition by log_id)=1
    and sum(CASE WHEN groupid in (1048,598,428) then 1 end) over (partition by log_id)=1
    then 1000